# Deployed a Next.js application to App Engine Standard [Nodejs] and got a 500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I deployed to app engine with nodejs8 runtime and got a 500. Im deploying a next.js application, and upon reviewing StackDriver I get. It appears .next might be getting ignored. The error is as follows:

```
throw new Error("Could not find a valid build in the '".concat(this.distDir, "' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server."));

Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/srv/build' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server. at Server.readBuildId (/srv/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:753:15) at new Server (/srv/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:80:25) at module.exports (/srv/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:6:10) at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/server.js:10:13) at Module._compile (module.js:653:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10) at Module.load (module.js:566:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
```

My package.json file looks like:

```
   {
  "name": "emails",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "lint": "standard",
    "prestart": "next build", 
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "appspot-deploy": "gcloud app deploy --project=email-app-219521",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.2.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "memorystore": "^1.6.0",
    "next": "^7.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "styled-jsx-plugin-sass": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.x.x"
  }
}
```

And my app.yaml file looks like:

```
runtime: nodejs8
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: server.js
```

And Im serving up my project with express on port 8080.

Comment: Can you look at the stdout and stderr logs of your application in Stackdriver Loggingat https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer? Make sure to select "GAE Application" in the resource picker. Please update your post with what you see in the logs.

`gcloud alpha services list --available` and your screenshots do not seem to be related to App Engine.

Comment: We had similar problems, and this more recent answer from `vercel` did the job:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12474

Turns out GAE does not like the .next directory, so it needs to look for a build directory instead. Check the link for additional setup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When your application is returning 500 errors, make sure to look at the `stdout` and `stderr` logs of your application in Stackdriver Logging at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer. Double check that you are looking at "GAE Application" resource picker.

Looking at the error message, it seems that the `.next` folder does not exist in your app. This `.next` folder is a folder that is usually generated via a "build step", and I see indeed that you have `"build": "next build"` as a `script` in your `package.json`.

You should not be using `prestart` to perform this build step, first because App Engine does not run `prestart` on instance startup, but also because in general this would be bad for performances.

You have two ways to create this folder:

1. Generate `.next` on your machine before deploying, to do so, you can change your `deploy` script to be: `"deploy": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy"`. (And also make sure that the `.gcloudignore` file does not contain `.next` or does not include the content of the `.gitignore` file)
2. Run this build step on Google Cloud's servers after deploying: The Node.js App Engine runtime will execute any `gcp-build` script if present. This means that you can add this script: `"gcp-build": "npm run build"` to your `package.json`. When doing so, I recommend you to add `.next` to the `.gcloudignore` file so that the `.next` folder does not get uploaded at deployment time.

In addition, note that you can simplify your `app.yaml` to just `runtime: nodejs8`:

- `NODE_ENV` is automatically set to `production`, you can remove it
- Your handlers section is equivalent to the default one.

Comment: Thanks Steren, Im up and running now after changing my deploy script to what you suggested and cleaned up the other items you mentioned. I've seen various examples out there to include one person using the prestart build stepp for GAE as well as another stating that .next is ignored and requires a next.config key value of distDir: 'build'. Neither of those solutions worked.

Comment: I ended up here because I can't quite get the `gcp-build` & next.js build working either. In fact, I can't even determine from looking at verbose deploy logs and stackdriver logging that `gcp-build` even executes. It would be fairly valuable if this works as described in https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/announcing-nodejs-10-for-app-engine but i'm not sure how to debug it further given the limited amount of documents about it online.

Answer (score 3):

I've just managed to make it work. Here's what I found:

First of all, it doesn't work with Yarn. It seems `gcp-build` command does not run when there is `yarn.lock` file.

Now in `package.json`, use following scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "gcp-build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  }
```

And make sure to declare Next and all modules needed in `next.config.js` as **dependencies** (not devDependencies)

FYI I only have `runtime: nodejs10` in my `app.yaml` and only scripts I have are in `pages` folder and `next.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I removed a file that one of my pages (in the /pages folder) happened to be referencing.

Either restore that file, or remove the file that is referencing the missing file.